# Mac User - How do I set CLASSPATHS in Mac (I'm working on a Lucene Demo)

Tags: java, macos, lucene, classpath

I'm trying to get my Apache Lucene demo to work and I'm down to setting the classpath in this tutorial http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/demo.html

I've hunted the web and these wer the 2 solutions I found to set CLASSPATH:

```
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar
```

and

```
setenv CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar
```

The second one brings up a error
-bash: setenv: command not found

The first one seemed to accept ok but wen i tried the next step in the tutorial i got an error. The next step was to run the following:

```
Phil-hunters-MacBook:webapps philhunter$ java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/src
```

which gave me the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles

This leads me to believe my CLASSPATHS didnt set correctly. Would I be right in assuming this? I have tried other tutorials and demos and see to get this same error quite a bit. Im new to Lucene and relatively new to mac and Unix shell scripting. Anyone know if I am setting the CLASSPATH correctly and if thats the cause of the errors?

Comment: Still no luck with this. Im getting and:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexHTML
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexHTML
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you set an environment variable like `CLASSPATH` then by default it only applies to the current process (i.e. the shell process itself) - it isn't available to the java process you launch in the next line. In order to make it available to other processes you need to "export" the variable.  In this case you can use something like:

```
export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar
```

This basically says "set the CLASSPATH variable to its current value plus the location of the lucene jar, and make the new variable available to any processes launched from this shell".

However, with java the usual way of setting the classpath is to do it as part of the `java` command itself, using the `-classpath` or `-cp` options. In your case it would look something like:

```
Phil-hunters-MacBook:webapps philhunter$ java -cp /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles /Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/src
```

As an aside, the error you see when using the `setenv` line is because `setenv` is the command used in the C shell to set environment variables, but the default Mac shell (and the shell you're using) is `bash` which doesn't recognise `setenv` and lets you know it doesn't recognise it with the error message: `-bash: setenv: command not found`.

Answer (score 11):

in the terminal type

```
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
```

edit the file and add one line:

```
export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/usr/local/lucene-3.6.2/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:/usr/local/lucene-3.6.2/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.6.2.jar;
```

make sure to change the path of yours.

In your way you lose to add lucene-demo-3.0.3.jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

i create a .bash_profile file in my home directory and do things like

```
export GRAILS_HOME=/usr/share/grails
...
export PATH=${GRAILS_HOME}/bin:${GROOVY_HOME}/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.1.45-osx10.6-x86_64/bin:${PATH}
```

you can work of that to set the classpath -- these examples show how to declare an environment variable and how to use the variable in other variables.

Comment: +1 The default shell on Mac OS X is `bash`. See also http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/froomin/Handouts/Shell_Ref_Page.html

Comment: This doesnt make sense to be about creating a .bash_profile file. Im not sure what to do.

Comment: @user544006 -- what does not make sense?  You need to create a file '.bash_profile' in your home directory, and add the relevant commands to set up your environment.

Comment: export PHIL_HOME=/Users/philhunter

CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar

CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/philhunter/Desktop/COM562\ Project/lucene-3.0.3/lucene-demo-3.0.3.jar
...................
This is my file that i saved in /Users/philhunter called .bash_profile
Is that correct??