# What is path of JDK lib on MacOSx?

Tags: java, git, classpath

I want to delete a file which commited to the Github Repo accidentaly, so I decide to take `bfg` method to delete this file completely, https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#speed, but an exception occurs to me:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile bfg.jar

I guess I don't put the `bfg.jar` into the right path, any idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard installation for the JDK is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. If `bfg.jar` is missing from your classpath try following the answer provided here:

[Mac User - How do i set CLASSPATHS in Mac (I'm working on a Lucene Demo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869024/mac-user-how-do-i-set-classpaths-in-mac-im-working-on-a-lucene-demo)

Comment: Thank you @Keith, what's the exactly lib path of the installed jdk on MacOSx?

Comment: Well, on mine (Yosemite 10.10.5), it's at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/lib`

Comment: Well, The path of bfg-1.12.5.jar is: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/bfg-1.12.5.jar`, but the exception still take place: `Error: Unable to access jarfile bfg-1.12.5.jar`

Comment: What is the command you're running on the shell, and what is in your jar's manifest?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter where you put the `bfg.jar` file, as long as you reference it using this location when calling the command.

Example (assuming you're using Linux or Mac OS X, adjust the path syntax if you're using Windows):

- Download the `bfg.jar` file to `$HOME/bfg.jar`. Rename the file if required, the original download has the version number in there, e.g. `bfg-1.12.5.jar`.
- Use Explorer, Finder or another tool to verify that the file is in the right location and has the correct name.
- Open a Terminal/Shell in the parent folder of the Git repo that you want to clean up. If your Git repo is in `$HOME/workspaces/foo`, open the terminal in `$HOME/workspaces`
- Make sure that you have the `java` command on your path by executing `java -version`. This should display the Java version.
- Run the BFG command, using the path that you downloaded the file to, e.g.

  ```
  java -jar $HOME/bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M foo
  ```

I strongly recommend against putting downloaded Jar files in system locations - this will only lead to trouble. Put them somewhere safe and reference them as required.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, it does work for me according to your suggestion.