# Eclipse Launch Failure Mac

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse client is not launching due to an error as follows:

```
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.
```

[Error window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB8ut.png)

However, my Java configuration window contradicts the Eclipse error.

[Java Update window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIwVl.png)

If there is no way to fix this at the moment, does anybody have a recommendation for Eclipse replacements for Macintoshes?

Thanks,

Tavin

Comment: did you define the jre or jdk to your classpath?

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869024/mac-user-how-do-i-set-classpaths-in-mac-im-working-on-a-lucene-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the full JDK of Java 8 installed not just the JRE.

There should be no problem running Eclipse on Mac OS X.

If necessary you can edit the eclipse.ini file to point to the JDK but it should not normally be required.