# unable to set classpath in mac terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I'm trying to run java program from mac terminal. I need to refer the library path before compilation.i keep getting import error because its not referring to the jar files.i cant get this to work. Any advise on this would be helpful.

**Please find the below commands used:**

```
 export CLASSPATH=/Users/Documents//IOS/lib/Parser.jar, /Users/Documents/IOS/lib/Collector.jar

javac samplejava.java
```

Also, i need to run the whole thing as shell script(like how we run a batch job in windows). Please help me with a working sample.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869024/mac-user-how-do-i-set-classpaths-in-mac-im-working-on-a-lucene-demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
export CLASSPATH=/Users/Documents//IOS/lib/Parser.jar:/Users/Documents/IOS/lib/Collector.jar

javac samplejava.java
```

classpath separator is : (colon) in *nix and there should be no space.

Comment: i'm able to fix the classpath issue by following given instrusction. compilation issue is gone. but unable to run the program i'm trying to compile and run the code by using below commands:  `javac -classpath ".:/Users/OS/Autoinstrumentation/IOS/lib/Parser.jar:/Users/IOS-Autoinstrumentation/IOS/lib/Collector.jar:" sampleprogram.java`

Comment: `java -cp . sampleprogram` end with this error: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)`

Comment: Any advise on this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

create a .bash_profile file in your home directory with

`export CLASSPATH=/Users/Documents//IOS/lib/Parser.jar, /Users/Documents/IOS/lib/Collector.jar
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/`