# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook problem

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have finished a project in java that use POI 4.0.1 library. I am using a Mac, Eclipse and Java 8 update 201. I do not use Maven or similar. I’ve already read all the 22 past post about the argument but I can’t find a solution. When I test the program (composed by 10 classes with the main) with Eclipse, no problem. All it’s work. But when I try to launch the application from the command line I obtain the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
at Applicazione.main(Applicazione.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

I've already imported in Eclipse all the useful jar from POI. In particular:

- POI-4.0.1.jar
- POI-ooxml.jar
- POI-excelant.jar
- POI-ooxml-schemas-4.0.1.jar
- POI-scratchpad.jar

I tried various combinations of the previous jar. I tried to add xmlbeans-3.0.2.jar and others from lib folder. But nothing. In Eclipse it works but from command line no. 
I also tried to move the POI folder in Java folder. Nothing is changed.

I also found a file in my project named .classpath. If it can be helpful the content is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="con"      path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/path/Desktop/App/poi-4.0.1/poi-4.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/path/Desktop/App/poi-4.0.1/poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/path/Desktop/App/poi-4.0.1/poi-examples-4.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/path/Desktop/App/poi-4.0.1/poi-excelant-4.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/path/Desktop/App/poi-4.0.1/poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.1.jar"/>
```

```
</classpath>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that libraries that you used are on the class path when running in command line. Since all POI libraries are in the `/Users/path/Desktop/App/poi-4.0.1` director you can use:

```
java -cp "/Users/path/Desktop/App/poi-4.0.1:." Applicazione
```

There is no magic to `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. You simply don't have the right class path.

Comment: I've just tried. I went in my bin directory (/Users/path/Desktop/App/App/bin) and copy your line but I obtained the same error. How can I modify the classpath?

Comment: If it can be useful, my folder is App, on desktop. It contains another 2 folders: POI-4.0.1 and App. The second one contain the code (bin folder and src folder)

Comment: I tried to set the classpath but now the error is: Could not find or load main class Applicazione

Comment: Thanks anyway. I solved my problem reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869024/mac-user-how-do-i-set-classpaths-in-mac-im-working-on-a-lucene-demo